# C# create a fatal exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a strange scenario when my application can get into an infinite loop when shutting down. It occurs when it wants to do something but the calls fail as it no longer has access (time based). In such a scenario it should just stop.
I record failed attempts and if the count goes above a certain number in a certain time I throw an exception which I expect to start the JIT debugger and stop the application.
I am not entirely sure why it gets into the loop so I want the JIT window that gives me information like the call stack and application status.
I have exception handling, but what I want is to turn it off and somehow generate an exception that will trigger the JIT debugger, however, all other posts I have found have been for handling exceptions and avoid crashes.
If there is another way at runtime to have the application stop and tell me what is happening I would like to know.
Thanks.

Comment: You could always System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()

Comment: Why don't you run your app with the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You should try Debugger.Launch() and Debugger.Break() methods (but remember that you should use them only in development environment). You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kzs2ysh.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

will launch the debugger for you. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

> I have exception handling

Sounds to me that you have too much of it.  Only ever catch *specific* exception types, never catch Exception.  Now you can simply throw any *other* exception type and your app will bomb with an unhandled exception.  Which brings up the JIT debugger dialog on your dev machine, a merciful end on your customer's machine.

Using System.Diagnostics.Debugger is good too, but wrap it with #ifdef DEBUG.  Your customer doesn't have one.